# How to predict unlabelled data's sentiment using Gensim word2vec model?

Tags: python-3.7, gensim, word2vec, sentiment-analysis, valueerror

I trained and test the 'IMDb movie reviews dataset' using the Gensim word2vec model and I want to predict the sentiments of my own unlabelled data. I tried but got an error. I am reusing an open-source code. Below is the full code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import text_normalizer as tn
import model_evaluation_utils as meu
np.set_printoptions(precision=2, linewidth=80)
import gensim
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dropout, Activation, Dense
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

dataset = pd.read_csv(r'imdb_reviews.csv')
new_data = pd.read_csv('abcd.csv', header=0)
# take a peek at the data
print(dataset.head())
reviews = np.array(dataset['reviews'])
sentiments = np.array(dataset['Sentiments'])

# build train and test datasets
train_reviews = reviews[:35000]
train_sentiments = sentiments[:35000]
test_reviews = reviews[35000:]
test_sentiments = sentiments[35000:]

# normalize datasets
norm_train_reviews = tn.normalize_corpus(train_reviews)
norm_test_reviews = tn.normalize_corpus(test_reviews)
le = LabelEncoder()
num_classes=2 
# tokenize train reviews & encode train labels
tokenized_train = [tn.tokenizer.tokenize(text)
                   for text in norm_train_reviews]
y_tr = le.fit_transform(train_sentiments)
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_tr, num_classes)
# tokenize test reviews & encode test labels
tokenized_test = [tn.tokenizer.tokenize(text)
                   for text in norm_test_reviews]
y_ts = le.fit_transform(test_sentiments)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_ts, num_classes)
# print class label encoding map and encoded labels
print('Sentiment class label map:', dict(zip(le.classes_, le.transform(le.classes_))))
print('Sample test label transformation:\n'+'-'*35,
      '\nActual Labels:', test_sentiments[:3], '\nEncoded Labels:', y_ts[:3], 
      '\nOne hot encoded Labels:\n', y_test[:3])
# build word2vec model
w2v_num_features = 500
w2v_model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(tokenized_train, size=w2v_num_features, window=150,
                                   min_count=10, sample=1e-3)
def averaged_word2vec_vectorizer(corpus, model, num_features):
    vocabulary = set(model.wv.index2word)

    def average_word_vectors(words, model, vocabulary, num_features):
        feature_vector = np.zeros((num_features,), dtype="float64")
        nwords = 0.

        for word in words:
            if word in vocabulary: 
                nwords = nwords + 1.
                feature_vector = np.add(feature_vector, model[word])
        if nwords:
            feature_vector = np.divide(feature_vector, nwords)

        return feature_vector

    features = [average_word_vectors(tokenized_sentence, model, vocabulary, num_features)
                    for tokenized_sentence in corpus]
    return np.array(features)
# generate averaged word vector features from word2vec model
avg_wv_train_features = averaged_word2vec_vectorizer(corpus=tokenized_train, model=w2v_model,
                                                     num_features=500)
avg_wv_test_features = averaged_word2vec_vectorizer(corpus=tokenized_test, model=w2v_model,
                                                    num_features=500)
print('Word2Vec model:> Train features shape:', avg_wv_train_features.shape, ' Test features shape:', avg_wv_test_features
def construct_deepnn_architecture(num_input_features):
    dnn_model = Sequential()
    dnn_model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu', input_shape=(num_input_features,)))
    dnn_model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    dnn_model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
    dnn_model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    dnn_model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
    dnn_model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    dnn_model.add(Dense(2))
    dnn_model.add(Activation('softmax'))

    dnn_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',                 
                      metrics=['accuracy'])
    return dnn_model
w2v_dnn = construct_deepnn_architecture(num_input_features=500)
batch_size = 100
w2v_dnn.fit(avg_wv_train_features, y_train, epochs=15, batch_size=batch_size, 
            shuffle=True, validation_split=0.1, verbose=1)
y_pred = w2v_dnn.predict_classes(avg_wv_test_features)
predictions = le.inverse_transform(y_pred)
meu.display_model_performance_metrics(true_labels=test_sentiments, predicted_labels=predictions, 
                                      classes=['positive', 'negative'])
# This I added to predict and save the results of my own data
pred_y2 = w2v_dnn.predict_classes(new_data['Articles'])
print(pred_y2)
pd.DataFrame(pred_y2, columns=['Sentiments']).to_csv('abcd_sentiments.csv')
```

When I run this code I got the below error:

> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>   ----> 1 pred_y2 = w2v_dnn.predict_classes(new_data['Articles'])
>         2 print(pred_y2)
>         3 pd.DataFrame(pred_y2, columns=['Sentiments']).to_csv('abcd_sentiments.csv')
>
> ~/PycharmProjects/News/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/sequential.py
>   in predict_classes(self, x, batch_size, verbose)
>       266             A numpy array of class predictions.
>       267         """
>   --> 268         proba = self.predict(x, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose)
>       269         if proba.shape[-1] > 1:
>       270             return proba.argmax(axis=-1)
>
> ~/PycharmProjects/News/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py
>   in predict(self, x, batch_size, verbose, steps, callbacks,
>   max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)    1439     1440
>    # Case 2: Symbolic tensors or Numpy array-like.
>   -> 1441         x, _, _ = self._standardize_user_data(x)    1442         if self.stateful:    1443             if x[0].shape[0] > batch_size
>   and x[0].shape[0] % batch_size != 0:
>
> ~/PycharmProjects/News/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py
>   in _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight,
>   check_array_lengths, batch_size)
>       577             feed_input_shapes,
>       578             check_batch_axis=False,  # Don't enforce the batch size.
>   --> 579             exception_prefix='input')
>       580 
>       581         if y is not None:
>
> ~/PycharmProjects/News/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py
>   in standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis,
>   exception_prefix)
>       143                             ': expected ' + names[i] + ' to have shape ' +
>       144                             str(shape) + ' but got array with shape ' +
>   --> 145                             str(data_shape))
>       146     return data
>       147
>
> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have
>   shape (500,) but got array with shape (1,)

Can somebody suggest me how to solve this error and predict sentiments of my unlabeled data?
I am using python 3.7 and jupyter notebook from Pycharm IDE.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The problem does not related to the model but to the input. Check that the shape of ```avg_wv_train_features``` is actually ```(TRAIN_LEN,500)```

Comment: Yes the model is fine and running perfect (if remove last three line of code). My issue which I stated in my question also is that I want to predict unlabeled data and I added the last three lines for that. But that gives the error. So how to solve this and predict sentiments for my data?

Comment: You should show (in your question)  the full error stack that accompanies the error you've received, so answerers can see exactly which lines of your code, and the code you're calling, are involved.

Comment: I edited the question. Now have full error stack.